# List rows with buttons onTapGesture

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

I have a `List` with some `row`s and some `Button`s. I want to play different sounds for each button.

```
struct ContentView: View  {
let rows = Row.all()

var body: some View {
    List {
    
        ForEach(rows) { row in
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                ForEach(row.cells) { cell in
                    Button(
                        Image(cell.imageURL)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                        )
                        .onTapGesture {
                            //playAudioAsset(cell.imageURL + "Sound")
                            print(cell.imageURL)
                        }
                }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
            }.padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: -20, bottom: 0, trailing: -20))
        }
        }
```

Even this simple `print`doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `Button` does not need a `.onTapGesture`, it is included in a button.
Read-up on how to use a `Button`, and try this instead:

```
Button(action: {
    //playAudioAsset(cell.imageURL + "Sound")
    print(cell.imageURL)
}){
    Image(cell.imageURL)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
}
```